# How to generate a word cloud using elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an elasticsearch DB with data of the form

```
record = {#all but age are strings
            'diagnosis': self.diagnosis,
            'vignette': self.vignette,
            'symptoms': self.symptoms_list,
            'care': self.care_level_string,
            'age': self.age, #float
            'gender': self.gender
        }
```

I want to create a word cloud of the data in `vignette`.

I tried all sorts of queries and I get error 400, meaning I don't understand how to query the database.

I am using python

This is the only successful query I was able to come up with

```
   def search_phrase_in_vignettes(self, phrase):
        body = {
            "_source": ["vignette"],
            "query": {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "vignette": {
                        "query": phrase,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        res = self.es.search(index=self.index_name, doc_type=self.doc_type, body=body)
```

Which finds any record with `phrase` contained in the field `'vignette'

I am thinking some aggregation should do the trick, but I can't seem to be able to write a correct query with 'aggr'.

Would love some help on how to correctly write even the simplest query with aggregation in python.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/tag-that-cloud-a-new-visualization-in-kibana

Answer (score 2):

Use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for the approach words count. Your query will be:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "vignette": {
                "query": phrase,
            }
        }
    },    
    "aggs" : {
        "cloud" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "vignette" }
        }
    }
}
```

When you receive results take buckets from `aggregations` key:

```py
res = self.es.search(index=self.index_name, doc_type=self.doc_type, body=body)
for bucket in res['aggregations']['cloud']['buckets']:
    rest of build cloud
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. What you suggest gives me `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[match_phrase] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]')` I changed `"query": phrase to `"query": {"match_all": {}}`, and the rest is the same. Any thought?

Comment: You know, I had the client. I write script for my client, after two days he calls me: We change your script and now it does not work. Don't be as him...

Comment: The reason I changed the script was I don't want to query for a phrase, but for all the words, just like I wrote in the question. What should I put in the phrase in your case?

Comment: Delete query at all. And start read documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html